# Converting a pandas column from an array of string Quarters and Years to a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have the following dataframe

```
        Date        Data
0   [Q1, 10]         8.7
1   [Q2, 10]         8.4
2   [Q3, 10]        14.1
3   [Q4, 10]        16.2
4   [Q1, 11]        18.6
5   [Q2, 11]        20.4
6   [Q3, 11]        17.1
7   [Q4, 11]        37.0
8   [Q1, 12]        35.1
9   [Q2, 12]        26.0
10  [Q3, 12]        26.9
11  [Q4, 12]        47.8
12  [Q1, 13]        37.4
13  [Q2, 13]        31.2
14  [Q3, 13]        33.8
15  [Q4, 13]        51.0
16  [Q1, 14]        43.7
17  [Q2, 14]        35.2
18  [Q3, 14]        39.3
19  [Q4, 14]        74.5
20  [Q1, 15]        61.2
21  [Q2, 15]        47.5
22  [Q3, 15]        48.0
23  [Q4, 15]        74.8
24  [Q1, 16]        51.2
25  [Q2, 16]        40.4
26  [Q3, 16]        45.5
27  [Q4, 16]        78.3
28  [Q1, 17]        50.8
29  [Q2, 17]        38.5
30  [Q3, 17]        46.7
31  [Q4, 17]        77.3
32  [Q1, 18]        52.2
33  [Q2, 18]        41.3
34  [Q3, 18]        46.9
35  [Q4, 18]        68.4
36  [Q1, 19]        36.4
37  [Q2, 19]        33.8
38  [Q3, 19]        46.6
39  [Q4, 19]        73.8
40  [Q1, 20]        36.7
41  [Q2, 20]        37.6
```

I want to merge it into a `Date` into a Datetime object,

So `Q1,10` will become `Q1,2010` and then become `2010-03-31`

I tried the following code,

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.join('20'))
```

But it doesnt work.

i also tried using

```
df['Date'].astype(str)[:1]
```

to access the second column in the series to add a 20 at the front but it wont let me.

What the best way to convert this series into a pandas datatime column?

Comment: the column Date has lists or strings?

Comment: its an array of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create quarter [`PeriodIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html), then convert to datetimes by [`PeriodIndex.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.to_timestamp.html) and floor to days by [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
#if necessary create lists
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')

#test if format match
print ('20' + df['Date'].str[::-1].str.join(''))
0    2010Q1
1    2010Q2
2    2010Q3
3    2010Q4
4    2011Q1
5    2011Q2
Name: Date, dtype: object


df['Date'] = (pd.PeriodIndex('20' + df['Date'].str[::-1].str.join(''), freq='Q')
                .to_timestamp(how='e')
                .floor('d'))
print (df)
        Date  Data
0 2010-03-31   8.7
1 2010-06-30   8.4
2 2010-09-30  14.1
3 2010-12-31  16.2
4 2011-03-31  18.6
5 2011-06-30  20.4
```

Alternative for convert to `Period`s:

```
df['Date'] = (df['Date'].str[::-1].str.join('').apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='Q'))
                    .dt.to_timestamp(how='e')
                    .dt.floor('d'))
```

Or solution from @MrFuppes, thank you:

```
df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime("20"+df['Date'].str[::-1].str.join('')) + 
              pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0))
```

Comment: i get an error `TypeError: Incorrect dtype`

Comment: is it because its Q1 instead of 1Q

Comment: now i get `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`, maybe its my version of pandas i just updated it, what version are u using

Comment: @anarchy - I use `pandas           : 1.2.1`

Comment: my format matches exactly yours in the 2nd part, i just cant get to the last command

Comment: @anarchy - added another solution.

Comment: hey so i checked what dtype the column is, i also downgraded my pandas, its an object dtype, then i checked the type of data in each row and they are all strings, i still get `TypeError: Incorrect dtype
`

Comment: @anarchy - Is possible some another values like `NaN` Can you check `print (df[df['Date'].str[::-1].str.join('').isna()])`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229441/discussion-between-anarchy-and-jezrael).

Comment: hey @jezrael i have another question that is quite similar to this, please take a look if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455190/converting-a-pandas-column-from-an-array-of-string-quarters-and-years-to-a-datet