# Converting a pandas column from an array of string Quarters and Years to a datetime column where there is mixed formatting within the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

This is an extension of an earlier question i had.

[Converting a pandas column from an array of string Quarters and Years to a datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453901/converting-a-pandas-column-from-an-array-of-string-quarters-and-years-to-a-datet)

I have a dataframe like this where the dates are jumbled up.

I want to convert them to datetime objects.

So `3Q '11` would become `2011-09-30`
`Q1 '20` would become `2020-03-31`

```
Date    Data
3Q '11  11.12
4Q '11  15.43
1Q '12  11.8
2Q '12  17
1Q '13  19.5
2Q '13  14.62
3Q '13  14.1
4Q '13  26
1Q '14  16.4
2Q '14  13.3
3Q '14  12.3
4Q '14  21.4
1Q '15  12.6
2Q '15  11
3Q '15  9.9
4Q '15  16.1
1Q '16  10.3
Q2 '16  10
Q3 '16  9.3
Q4 '16  13.1
Q1 '17  8.9
Q2 '17  11.4
Q3 '17  10.3
Q4 '17  13.2
Q1 '18  9.1
Q2 '18  11.6
Q3 '18  9.7
Q4 '18  12.9
Q1 '19  9.9
Q2 '19  12.3
Q3 '19  11.8
Q4 '19  15.9
Q1 '20  6.9
Q2 '20  12.4
Q3 '20  13.9
```

I have the following formula to handle the different dataframes if the rows all match where either every row contains Q followed by a number or a number followed by a Q,

```
if df['Date'][0].startswith('Q') == True:
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace(" ","").str.split("'")
    df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime("20"+df['Date'].str[::-1].str.join('')) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0))
else:
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace("'","20").str.split(" ")
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.join('')) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)
```

However, in this case, the dataframe has both kinds of data where the dates are written written as both Q3 or 3Q within the same frame, how do i normalise the data before applying one of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) for correct order of periods and then apply solution for convert to datetimes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ["3Q '11", "4Q '11", "1Q '12", "2Q '12", "1Q '13",
                            "Q2 '19", "Q3 '19", "Q4 '19", "Q1 '20"], 
                   'Data': [11.12, 15.43, 11.8, 17.0, 19.5, 12.3, 11.8, 15.9, 6.9]})
print (df)
     Date   Data
0  3Q '11  11.12
1  4Q '11  15.43
2  1Q '12  11.80
3  2Q '12  17.00
4  1Q '13  19.50
5  Q2 '19  12.30
6  Q3 '19  11.80
7  Q4 '19  15.90
8  Q1 '20   6.90
```

---

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r"^(\d+)([Q])\D*(\d+)$", r'20\3\2\1', regex=True)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r"^([Q]\d+)\D*(\d+)$", r'20\2\1', regex=True)


print (df)
     Date   Data
0  2011Q3  11.12
1  2011Q4  15.43
2  2012Q1  11.80
3  2012Q2  17.00
4  2013Q1  19.50
5  2019Q2  12.30
6  2019Q3  11.80
7  2019Q4  15.90
8  2020Q1   6.90
```

Another idea is use indexing:

```
m =  df['Date'].str.startswith('Q')
df['Date'] = ('20' + df['Date'].str[-2:] + df['Date'].str[:2]
                  .where(m, df['Date'].str[1] + df['Date'].str[0]))
print (df)
     Date   Data
0  2011Q3  11.12
1  2011Q4  15.43
2  2012Q1  11.80
3  2012Q2  17.00
4  2013Q1  19.50
5  2019Q2  12.30
6  2019Q3  11.80
7  2019Q4  15.90
8  2020Q1   6.90
```

Comment: hey @jezrael there no change in the second half of the data

Comment: @anarchy - both solutions?

Comment: yeah both dont work, second one has an error

Comment: @anarchy - hmmm, it sems data related problem, is possible share data in excel like [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229441/discussion-between-anarchy-and-jezrael) ?

Comment: yeah sure, but i need to run out now, will share it later

Comment: @anarchy - added input sample data for testing, working nice, so I guess there should be some difference in not working data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229445/discussion-between-anarchy-and-jezrael).