# Convert multiple non date formats within same column into a proper pandas datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

This is an extension to my 2 questions which I posted earlier,

[Converting a pandas column from an array of string Quarters and Years to a datetime column where there is mixed formatting within the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66455190/converting-a-pandas-column-from-an-array-of-string-quarters-and-years-to-a-datet)

I have 10 kinds of date permutations in my date column. The formatting was not done properly by whoever compiled the data. I want to convert the following examples into date time objects.

`Q1 '19` becomes `2019-03-31`

`Q1 '19*` becomes `2019-03-31`

`1Q '19` becomes `2019-03-31`

`1Q '19*` becomes `2019-03-31`

`1Q' 19` becomes `2019-03-31`

`1Q' 19*` becomes `2019-03-31`

`Q1' 19` becomes `2019-03-31`

`Q1' 19*` becomes `2019-03-31`

`2019` becomes `2019-12-31`

`2019*` becomes `2019-12-31`

I have 20 different excel sheets where in the date column, the data is not very clean and it could be in any one of these formats. Is there a for if loop I can write to account for any of these formats and convert them into the right date?

Each excel file can have a mixed of any of these formats or just 1 of them.
The data could look like this

```
Date
1Q '19
2Q '19*
Q4' 19
2019*
2020
```

So have I have done code for the first 8 cases, but I come into errors when I come across the last 2.

Here is my code so far,

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('xlsx'):
        df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name='Data',skiprows=range(0,4))
        df = df.drop(columns='Unnamed: 0')    
        df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1':'Date'})
        df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('\*', '')
        df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r"^(\d+)([Q])\D*(\d+)$", r'20\3\2\1', regex=True)
        df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r"^([Q]\d+)\D*(\d+)$", r'20\2\1', regex=True)
        df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.join('')) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0))
```

Handle the last 2 cases within one code block with out running into errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':"1Q '19,2Q '19*,Q4' 19,2019*,2020".split(',')})

#first replace only years - for 4 digits add Q4
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str).replace(r"(\d{4})\D*", r'\1Q4', regex=True)
#replace 1234 with Q and add 2 digits for years
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r"^([1234])([Q])\D*(\d{2})\D*", r'20\3\2\1', regex=True)
#replace Q with 1234 and add 2 digits for years
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r"^([Q][1234])\D*(\d{2})\D*", r'20\2\1', regex=True)

print (df)
     Date
0  2019Q1
1  2019Q2
2  2019Q4
3  2019Q4
4  2020Q4
```

Comment: when i reach a file with these dates,
`2004 2005 2006 2007 2008`
I get the following error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`